# Entity manager best practices

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I would like to know which way is the best to define entity manager. I am using spring boot

case 1) creating in spring service class like follows

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DemoService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoService.class);

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public void getEntity(){
        final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @PersistenceUnit
    public void setEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

}
```

Case 2.) Define a global entity manager and share it across all services.

Note : Each service only reflects one single Entity definition.

Comment: 1. No, 2. No. Just add a field of type `EntityManager` annotate with `@PersistenceContext` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting the EntityManager is the simplest and the most effective way to do it:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

- You don't need to set the `EntityManagerFactory`, since you need a transaction-bound `EntityManager`.
- You don't need to hold the `EntityManager` in a global component, since that would be yet another indirection layer and you can simply mock the `EntityManager` anyway.